# Привязка IP к AWS

Tags: веб-программирование, ip, amazon-web-services

Собственно пытаюсь по инструкции привязать IP к AWS. Все вроде бы делаю как надо, но когда пытаюсь перейти по IP на свой сайт, то ничего не грузится. С чем может быть связано? [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как запущен сайт? на каком порту? какой URL открываете у себя?

Comment: `security groups` проверяли?

Comment: зайдите на инстанст. выполните `curl localhost:PORT`, это ваш сайт?

Comment: @Senior Pomidor 
Порт 80, скрин со ссылкой по которой открываю у себя ниже прикрепил

Comment: @Exploding Kitten security groups не проверял, никаких манипуляций там не делал, а надо?

Comment: да нужно, т.к. по умолчанию `security group` блокирует все, кроме того, что явно разрешено, если у вас нет правила для 80 порта, то и доступа к нему не будет, хотя Elastic Beanstalk мог это и сам сделать, нужно проверять

Answer (score 0):

1. Порт 80, у себя открываю: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. security groups не проверял, никаких манипуляций там не делал, а надо?
3. Если я вас правильно понял:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не является ответом. вы можете оставить комментарий, когда ваша репутация будет определенного уровня.  curl localhost:PORT - тут порт нужно менять на реальный порт на котором работает ваш веб-сервер